# How to pass parameters between two different menus in custom Community Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app

I need to pass Id from home menu to other on click. In the bellow image when we click on **TestProjectTD1**. Projects should be active and display the information of **TestProjectTD1**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot with what you are trying with [Navigaton Menu](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_setup_nav_menu.htm&type=5). The menus are static in nature and that on click of a particular record in another menu, you cannot pass any parameter dynamically or highlight another menu.

While not completely sure about your use case here, you seem to already have a list of Projects on the Home Page, then you don't really need another tab to show the same information. Clicking on a record link will always navigate to the record detail page as configured.